# Reference a constant from one function in another

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, variables, constants

I am attempting to send user information gathered from the facebookSDK and perform an HTTP POST sending the details I gathered stored in constants.

I am new to swift development and although this solution may be straight forward I am unable to configure a workable solution.

I need to pass the data in the fetchProfile() function into the data_request() function to pass data to the API.

[The image shows the data_request function, highlighted is the line where i need to reference the data stored in constants within the fetchProfile() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8vbF.png)

[This image shows the fetchProfile() function holding the data needed to be passed to data_request()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvIbp.png)

Any feedback or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. Relevant code belongs directly into your question in text form, not as image on external sites.

Answer (score 1):

Both your function have closures, which means the call back from a async network call. So your main function will finish first, and then when your network call is finished, the closure is called. So in your situation, you need to wait until `fetchProfile()` finished the async call in order to get data, and then use it in `data_request()` function. So it will look like

```
func fetchProfile(){
    //...
    FBSDKGraphRequest....
        void in
        //prepare your data here
        //call data_request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving upon the answer posted by Fangming, you need to pass the data received in fetchProfile() to data_request() and call it at the end of the completion block of `FBSDKGraphRequest.start`. This is how it should look like:

```
func fetchProfile() {
    FBSDKGraphRequest(...).start {
        // create a dictionary to hold all the values returned
        let values: [String: Any]

        // fetch all values in to the dictionary 
        // ...

        // call data_request by passing URL and the dictionary
        data_request(url, params: values)
    }
}
```

Now the `data_request` function should look like this now:

```
func data_request(url: String, params: [String: Any]) {
    // your implementation here
}
```